# Mule Quartz - Cron for all week days except 1st day of month

Tags: mule, quartz-scheduler

The cron expression `0 30 4 2-31 * MON-FRI *` is invalid because of error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.
```

But maybe there is another way to specify such cron expression:

> Execute every weekday except first day of month on 4:30.

Is it possible using `W` parameter?

I'm using Quartz Crone expression in MuleSoft `quartz:inbound-endpoint` configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/CronExpression.html

Support for specifying both a day-of-week and a day-of-month value is not complete (you'll need to use the '?' character in one of these fields).

You could use `0 30 4 ? * MON-FRI *`

**At 04:30:00am, every day between Monday and Friday, every month**

You could do an expression filter check to see if today's date is not the first, and then proceed.

```
<expression-filter expression="#[server.dateTime.getDayOfMonth() != 1]" doc:name="Expression"/>
```

Comment: Good idea. I'll try the expression - it should works - I'll check tomorrow. Thanks.